# 'HttpRequest' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, httprequest, google-search-console

I want to use Search Console API and therefore I have a piece of code. However I can not get rid of the error: '`TypeError: 'HttpRequest' object is not subscriptable`'

What I want to achieve: get more data from Google Search Console.

I am using latest Spyder combined with latest Anaconda, Python 3.7

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import httplib2
import pyasn1_modules
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from collections import defaultdict
from dateutil import relativedelta
import argparse
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import file
from oauth2client import tools

CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH = r'gsc_client_secret.json'

site = 'https://www.XXX.nl'

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly']
DISCOVERY_URI = ('https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/customsearch/v1/rest') 

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
    parents=[tools.argparser])
flags = parser.parse_args([])

flow = client.OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id=XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                           client_secret='XXX',
                           scope=SCOPES)

storage = file.Storage(r'C:\\Users\\XXX\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\bs4\\searchconsolereporting.dat')
credentials = storage.get()

if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
  credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
http = credentials.authorize(http=httplib2.Http())

webmasters_service = build('webmasters', 'v3', http=http)

end_date = datetime.date.today()-relativedelta.relativedelta(days=3)
start_date = end_date

def execute_request(service, property_uri, request):
    return service.searchanalytics().query(siteUrl=property_uri, body=request)

maxRows = 25000; 
i = 0;
numRows = maxRows;
scDict = defaultdict(list);

while (numRows == 25000) :
    request = {
        'startDate': datetime.datetime.strftime(start_date,"%Y-%m-%d"),
        'endDate': datetime.datetime.strftime(end_date,'%Y-%m-%d'),
        'dimensions': ['date','page','query'],
        'rowLimit': maxRows, 
        'startRow': i*maxRows
    }
    response = execute_request(webmasters_service, site, request)

    for row in response['rows']:
        scDict['date'].append(row['keys'][0] or 0)    
        scDict['page'].append(row['keys'][1] or 0)
        scDict['query'].append(row['keys'][2] or 0)
        scDict['clicks'].append(row['clicks'] or 0)
        scDict['ctr'].append(row['ctr'] or 0)
        scDict['impressions'].append(row['impressions'] or 0)
        scDict['position'].append(row['position'] or 0)

    df = pd.DataFrame(data = scDict)
    df['clicks'] = df['clicks'].astype('int')
    df['ctr'] = df['ctr']*100
    df['impressions'] = df['impressions'].astype('int')
    df['position'] = df['position'].round(2)
    df.sort_values('clicks',inplace=True,ascending=False)
    numRows=len(response['rows'])
    i=i+1

df.to_csv(r"XXX\\gsc_api_exports\\GSC_backups.csv",index=False)

##currentcsv=pd.read_csv(r"XXX\\gsc_api_exports\\GSC_backups.csv")
##currentcsv=currentcsv.append(df,ignore_index=True)
##currentcsv.to_csv(r"XXX\\gsc_api_exports\\GSC_backups.csv",index=False)
```

Does anyone have a clue how to fix this?

Comment: post the full traceback so we can see where the error occurs.

Answer (score 2):

You are not calling `.execute()` on the request in your `execute_request` function.

```
response = service.searchanalytics().query(siteUrl=domain, body=request).execute()
rows = response["rows"]
```

The [quick start guide](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/quickstart/quickstart-python) in Google's documentation is pretty good